# Array values from list containing indices using Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I would like to get array values of `A` based on indices mentioned in list `B`. The desired output is attached.

```
import numpy as np
A=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
B=[(0,0),(1,0),(2,1),(2,2)]
```

The desired output should look like

```
[1,4,8,9]
```

Comment: `A[(*zip(*B), )]` -> `array([1, 4, 8, 9])`

Answer (score 0):

The first step of the trick to be used here is:

- create a *Numpy* array from *B*,
- transpoose it,
- convert to a tuple of tuples.

The code to do it is:

```
tuple(map(tuple, np.array(B).T))
```

For your source data the result is:

```
((0, 1, 2, 2), (0, 0, 1, 2))
```

The first inner tuple contains row indices, the second - column indices.

Then you can use it to retrieve indicated elements of *A*, using `A[…]`.

So the whole code to get your expected elements is:

```
A[tuple(map(tuple, np.array(B).T))]
```

Another, shorter option is:

```
A[tuple(np.array(B).T)]
```

This time `tuple(np.array(B).T)` yields a tuple, made of 1-D *Numpy*
arrays, made of rows of *np.array(B).T*.